# Batch insert takes incredible long time

Tags: java, mysql

We have some trouble inserting lots of rows at once.
We are running the project on a machine to localhost MySQL database, ensuring the performance of the server shouldn't be the problem.
Is there anything to do about this long inserting time?

The comment in the code explains exactly what line that gives us the problem

```java
public <T> void batchExecute(String query, BatchArgSetter<T> batchArgSetter) {
    Connection con = this.getConnection();
    PreparedStatement statement = null;
    int i = 0;
    try {
        con.setAutoCommit(false);
        statement = con.prepareStatement(query);
        while (batchArgSetter.hasNext()) {
         // This code to set args and add batch is instant. About 0.05 ms per per 1000.
            setArgs(statement, batchArgSetter.getArgs(batchArgSetter.next()));
            statement.addBatch();
            i++;
            if (i % 1000 == 0 || i == batchArgSetter.getSize()) {

             // However, this line takes forever.
             // About 30 seconds per batch. A test with 9600 entries took a total time of 5min 42sec
             // We tried testing a collection of 100k+ entries, which we stopped after id had run 10min +
                statement.executeBatch();
                con.commit();
            }
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        closeAll(statement, null, con);
    }
}
```

### Setup of SQL class

```java
public class SqlConnection {
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private String url;
    private HikariConfig config = new HikariConfig();
    private HikariDataSource ds;

    public SqlConnection(Setting.PersistenceSetting setting) {
        this.username = setting.getUsername();
        this.password = setting.getPassword();
        this.url = "jdbc:mysql://" + setting.getUrl() + ":" + setting.getPort() + "/" + setting.getDatabase() + "?serverTimezone=UTC";
        setup(setting.getPoolSize());
    }


    private void setup(int poolSize) {
        config.setJdbcUrl(url);
        config.setUsername(username);
        config.setPassword(password);
        config.addDataSourceProperty("cachePrepStmts", "true");
        config.addDataSourceProperty("prepStmtCacheSize", "250");
        config.addDataSourceProperty("prepStmtCacheSqlLimit", "2048");
        config.setMaximumPoolSize(poolSize);
        config.setLeakDetectionThreshold(2000);
        config.setAutoCommit(true);
        ds = new HikariDataSource(config);
    }
```

### The code where I call my SQL method

```java
    private void insertMembers(List<Member> members) {
        sql.batchExecute("INSERT INTO user VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE username = ?, discriminator = ?, avatar = ?;", new BatchArgSetter<Member>(members) {
            @Override
            public Object[] getArgs(Member m) {
                return new Object[]{
                        m.getIdLong(),
                        m.getUser().getName(),
                        m.getUser().getDiscriminator(),
                        m.getUser().getEffectiveAvatarUrl(),

                        m.getUser().getName(),
                        m.getUser().getDiscriminator(),
                        m.getUser().getEffectiveAvatarUrl()
                };
            }
        });
        sql.batchExecute("INSERT INTO guild_member VALUES (?, ?, ?) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE nickname=?", new BatchArgSetter<Member>(members) {
            @Override
            public Object[] getArgs(Member member) {
                return new Object[]{
                        member.getIdLong(),
                        member.getGuild().getIdLong(),
                        member.getNickname(),
                        member.getNickname()
                };
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include the full source code you have as a [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others.
Also see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query for SQL related questions.

Comment: Now one commit spans ALL inserts, perhaps one per 1000 would be better. But I doubt, that it will make a huge difference. I'd have a look at some db numbers. the java side seems clean now. Proper indexes and certainty, that they get used would be good, otherwise you end up with one full table scan per insert/update.